# Array swapLargest not passing all tests, BASIC JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I've been trying to complete this problem for about 2 days now since it's the weekend and I can't contact any tutors at my school. I have made a loop that finds the highest value in a non-empty array and then swaps the lowest index of the highest number in that array with the last value in the array.

For example

swapLargest([1, 7, 5, 7, 4, 2]) → [1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 7]

but running it comes out as

[1, 7, 5, 7, 2, 4]

here is my code

```
int[] swapLargest(int[] a) {

 int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(int i = 1; i <a.length; i++){ // starting from 0
  if(a[i]  > max){
    max = a[i];
    max = i;

  }

}
 int temp = a[max];
 a[max]=a[a.length-1];
 a[a.length-1] = temp;
 return a;



}
```

and finally a link to the problem: http://codingbat.com/prob/p227094 if you'd like to test your results with mine. so far this would pass 4/11 tests.

I'm really new to programming, any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `max = a[i]; max = i` You're assigning to the same variable twice - the result of the first assignment is overwritten by the second. Maybe you need to assign to two different variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can store index of the max value in separate variable:

```
int[] swapLargest(int[] a) {

 int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 int maxI = 0 ;

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(a[i]  > max){
    max = a[i];
    maxI = i;

  }

}
 int temp = a[maxI];
 a[maxI]=a[a.length-1];
 a[a.length-1] = temp;
 return a;
}
```

Comment: It will give Syntactical error in checking condition of for loop and also one logical error is that you are starting iterating through array to find maximum element from the index `1` So If the maximum element is at 1st position, this code would fail there.